# Set up rancher host on windows

Tags: windows, macos, rancher

I installed rancher server on my mac osx.
Then I have a windows computer where i want to deploy my host.

I ran the command line which looks like so on my window computer:

```
docker run -d --privileged -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /var/lib/rancher:/var/lib/rancher rancher/agent:v1.0.1 http://192.168.99.100:8080/v1/scripts/E915A1D0B7E952F73D4E:1466539200000:MoUKnbVNKKFV8Q4CDbDMI2DvPQ
```

But the host doest not appear in the hosts lists.
Is there any configuration I have to set up on the windows machine like opening a port or whatever ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows support is something we are working on, but not supported yet.  The agent needs a fair bit of rework to work on Windows.

Comment: Update on it: the support for windows hosts is a #1 priority and is planned in 1.2.0 release (October 28 as I see in milestones) - https://github.com/rancher/rancher/issues/4576 https://github.com/rancher/rancher/milestone/67